# How to know where data comes from in a UNION mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, union

I have this mysql result query:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
   ( SELECT 
         * 
     FROM userA 
     UNION 
     SELECT 
         * 
     FROM userB 
     UNION 
     SELECT 
         * 
     FROM userC ) AS friendresult 
ORDER BY create_date DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 15
```

In order to retrieve data I use a mysql_fetch_array but I'd like to know the source of every row I fetch.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select a new column, to indicate from which table the data come from. Something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT *, 'userA' AS ComesFrom FROM userA 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 'userB'              FROM userB 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 'userC'              FROM userC
) AS friendresult 
ORDER BY create_date DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 15
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when I fetch data with mysql_fetch_array what should I write inside the square brackets to retrieve the table name?   Sorry for my incompetence ;)

Comment: @FedericoCapello - You will expect a new column `ComesFrom`, you have to read this column's value, put it in the square brackets: `$row['ComesFrom']`; it should contain the tablename the row comes from; if it is `userA` then it comes from the table `userA`, if it is `userB` then it comes from `userC`.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal . . . Because you are assigning different values for each source, you should use `union all` rather than `union` for performance reasons.